# how can I check if queries running on the codeigniter system is lacking a conditions using a php script

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Firstly, thanks every one that the question has piqued interest of you to see at least, what I wrote.

I use codeigniter framework. Recently, I am in need of creating a script or method using which I can search through all the models created in the whole system whether all the queries which are running has a specific condition.

Example:

Custom_model.php

```
$this->db->select('*')->where( array( 'some_id' => 1, 'id' => $id ) )->get('table_name')->result_array();

$this->db->select('*')->where( array( 'id' => $id ) )->get('table_name')->result_array();
```

Custom_model_2.php

```
$this->db->select('*')->where( array( 'id' => $id ) )->get('table_name')->result_array();

$this->db->select('*')->where( array( 'some_id' => 2, 'id' => $id ) )->get('table_name')->result_array();
```

I want to run a script which will check every query in the codeigniter model whether the query has the condition **'some_id'**

That way I can see if there is any missing condition in the whole system.

Thanks in advance all of who will at least, try to give me feedback.

**IF** there is any easy work around of it, please, mention it and help me in the case.

Comment: Simplest way is to just search for $this->db and eyeball all your statements to check them. If you have missing conditions, your code wont work which you would also see during your verification/debug process.

Comment: is it possible to print all the queries controller-wise or setting up a script in hook to fetch queries from a controller of which the view is rendered?

Comment: Hi @BattleHawk : try in the hook or controller var_dump( $this->db );

Comment: Also you can use the profiler https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html